# Distinct random variables in sampling

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. random variables with $X_1 \sim U[0,1]$.
>   Throwing out a null set all the variables are distinct.

Can anyone explain this second sentence? What does he mean with "throwing out a null set"?

Comment: It means that the sets $\{ X_i = X_j \}$ have measure zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, "with probability $1$, the $X_i$ are distinct", or "the event that the $X_i$ are not distinct is a null set".